# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn doesn't bind correctly

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am trying to add Combo box to datagridview and bind the combo with data and value. This is what I am doing and I ends up with many exceptions. What am I doing wrong?

```
        IList<string> houseNums= myTable.Select(x => house_num).ToList();

        dealersGridView.Columns.Clear();
        dealersGridView.DataSource = myTable;
        dealersGridView.Columns["id"].DisplayIndex = 1;
        dealersGridView.Columns["id"].HeaderText = "Field 1";
        dealersGridView.Columns["name"].DisplayIndex = 2;
        dealersGridView.Columns["name"].HeaderText = "Field 1";
        dealersGridView.Columns.Remove("house_num");
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        column.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
        column.DisplayIndex = 8;
        column.HeaderText = "MyHeader";
        column.DataSource = houseNums;
        dealersGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

The combo data doesn't bind and I don't see the selected values. What is wrong?..

Comment: What exceptions are you getting and where exactly?

Comment: @Bojan Skrchevski: I got many and different exceptions. Does my code makes sanse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that one of your problems is that you are adding values to the Items collection:

```
column.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
```

and then you are again setting the `DataSource` property

```
column.DataSource = houseNums;
```

you need to do one or the other not both.

```
foreach (string e in houseNums) column.Items.Add(e);
```

or:

```
column.DataSource = myTable.Select(x => house_num).ToList();
```

[Here's an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404353.aspx) and an example hot to populate DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from a `List<T>`.

One more thing. I noticed that you are selecting in a list from a table. I assume that this is a database table. You could bind a specific field from that table to the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource.aspx) property.